# ionic 3 sortable grids or tables

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using this to mimic an ionic table: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjzKMZ

```
<ion-content>
        <div class="row header">
          <div class="col">Utility Company Name</div>
          <div class="col">Service Code</div>
          <div class="col">Pay Limit</div>
          <div class="col">Account Number to Use</div>
          <div class="col">Actions</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="data in ctrl.data">
          <div class="col">{{data.name}}</div>
          <div class="col">{{data.code}}</div>
          <div class="col">LK {{data.limit}}</div>
          <div class="col">{{data.account}}</div>
          <div class="col"><button class="button">Add</button></div>
        </div>
</ion-content>
```

I want to be able to sort by column. Is this possible with Ionic 3?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to use Angular [**ag-grid**](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/). It has column sorting feature and lot more out of the box.

```
npm install ag-grid
```